# How can I align the product buttons on WooCommerce?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I am trying to align buttons of products on WooCommerce when displaying multiple products using an Elementor widget, but can't seem to align them without extending the width.

You can see an example on [www.faceup-romanorte.com](http://www.faceup-romanorte.com)

I used the auto-align button on Elementor Pro, and while it does align buttons vertically, it extends buttons to full width of the container containing the product, making them look off. I was expecting to only align buttons vertically down so that they all look at the same height of the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `title` of the product is pushing the button down, that's why we have to add a minimum height to all of them for them to appear at the same distance, like so:

```
.woocommerce-loop-product__title{min-height: 50px}
```

Tell me if this fixes your issue.

Comment: Tried this as custom css on the container but it didn't work... any ideas?

Comment: This ended up working

.eael-product-gallery .woocommerce ul.products li.product .woocommerce-loop-product__title {
    min-height: 35px;
}